# ISNULL not working in order in CAKEPHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp-2.0

I am using LEFT join and as a result getting null values for is_read column in Messages table. I want to keep the nulls at bottom when ordering. I'm using this in paginator. Following is the my code for doing the same:

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
        'fields' => array('User.*'),
        'joins' => array(
            array('table' => 'messages',
                'alias' => 'Message',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'User.id = Message.user_from_id'
                )
            ),
        ),
        'limit' => 20,
        'group' => array('User.id'),
        'order' => array('ISNULL(Message.is_read)' => 'asc','Message.is_read' => 'asc', 'Message.created' => 'asc'),
    );
```

The query Cakephp generates for this is as follows:

```
SELECT `User`.*, (CONCAT(`User`.`first_name`, ' ', `User`.`last_name`)) AS `User__full_name` FROM `srs_development`.`users` AS `User` LEFT JOIN `srs_development`.`messages` AS `Message` ON (`User`.`id` = `Message`.`user_from_id`) WHERE 1 = 1 GROUP BY `User`.`id` ORDER BY `Message`.`is_read` asc, `Message`.`created` asc LIMIT 20
```

ISNULL function is getting omitted in the final query. 
Also please suggest a way to accomplish this without using custom pagination() if possible.

Comment: Why are you ordering based on `ISNULL(x)` and `x` at the same time? Maybe you want `IFNULL(x, 0)`.

Comment: I tried to do it with IFNULL(x,0) also but that is also not working. If i just use IFNULL(Message.is_read, 0) then this order by clause gets ommitted from the resulting query.

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions, the use of `GROUP BY` is inappropriate. Perhaps you meant to use the `DISTINCT` operator.

Comment: I do understand that it is inappropriate to use group by without aggregating functions, but that should not be effecting the query. Moreover I have also tried using fields as

    'fields' => array('User.*', 'MAX(`Message`.created) AS message_date', 'SUM(IF(`Message`.is_read = 0, 1, 0)) AS unread'),

Comment: I am not sure you can put ISNULL in the order clause of CakePHP.  It does some data scrubbing before generating the clause, which (I believe) helps stop sql injection.  If you feel like reading code, see the 'order' function within the DboSource class.  There is another SO post where the poster needed to use a virtual field.  Besides virtual fields, you could make your first field `ISNULL(Message.is_read) AS sortme`.  Then try to put `sortme` in the order clause (or even the digit 1)

Comment: Thank @AgRizzo, your comment helped me to look in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate functions didn't work in the order clause when using Pagination component. I tried declaring a virtual field in Message model as:

```
public $virtualFields = array(
'sortme' => "ISNULL(Message.is_read)",
);
```

So finally, declaring it as virtual field in the Message model did the job.
Thank you everyone.